# My /var/log/ is mysteriously filling up GBs in minutes!

Tags: linux, logs, size

syslog fills the system hard disk in minutes. This is what logs shows:

```
Dec  6 14:03:01 ubuntu kernel: [   18.515567] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:   device [8086:9d15] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
Dec  6 14:03:01 ubuntu kernel: [   18.515569] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:    [ 0] Receiver Error         (First)
Dec  6 14:03:01 ubuntu kernel: [   18.515574] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Corrected error received: id=00e5
Dec  6 14:03:01 ubuntu kernel: [   18.516217] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: can't find device of ID00e5
Dec  6 14:03:01 ubuntu kernel: [   18.516219] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Corrected error received: id=00e5
Dec  6 14:03:01 ubuntu kernel: [   18.516227] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: can't find device of ID00e5
Dec  6 14:03:01 ubuntu kernel: [   18.516230] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Corrected error received: id=00e5
Dec  6 14:03:01 ubuntu kernel: [   18.516241] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, id=00e5(Receiver ID)
```

These are three new Asus F541U Laptops with Ubuntu 16 Dual Boot Windows 10. All of them experience the same issue with different grades of severity.

The system works good besides that. Everything is updated.

Is there a proper way to solve it? should I just ignore it and try to avoid the lines being output in the first place? how ?

I read some similar post where the solutions are to unmount or blacklist the culprit (pcieport - ID00e5 ?) or restrict the directory size but not sure about this.

I'm currently working by using:

```
for i in /var/log/*; do cat /dev/null > $i; done
```

all the time...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As described in [the launchpad bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1521173), you need to add `pci=noaer` to your kernel command line.

Summary, taken from the above bug report:

1. Edit `/etc/default/grub`. Change the line starting with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` into

   ```
    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=noaer"
   ```
2. Run `sudo update-grub`.
3. Reboot.

I recommend that you reboot first, without making the above modifications, and rather than let Grub auto-boot, edit the boot specification; edit the line containing `quiet` and `splash` by adding (a space and) `pci=noaer`.

If the machine works fine if booted like that, and the syslog is no longer spammed, you can safely make the above edits.

Comment: Thats right! found it here http://askubuntu.com/questions/771899/pcie-bus-error-severity-corrected. thanks

Comment: Thanks, fixed my slackware 14.2x64 problem when installed on an hp laptop (desktop installs didn't exhibit this problem)

Answer (score 0):

I found a bug-report trianged also to ubuntu xenial. Try workaround from there

[pci=noaer](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1521173) as bootoption.

Too slow again :D